# RSelenium and Chrome not displaying the complete page

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

Trying to navigate using `RSelenium`, however, the complete page is not loaded and several element text is missing. Works fine using FireFox, not Chrome.

Example code

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(port = 4567L, browser = 'chrome')
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate('https://www.r-bloggers.com/')
```

How it looks for me[image: r-bloggers]

RSelenium 1.7.3

Info when running `rsDriver`

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$acceptInsecureCerts
[1] FALSE

$acceptSslCerts
[1] FALSE

$applicationCacheEnabled
[1] FALSE

$browserConnectionEnabled
[1] FALSE

$browserName
[1] "chrome"

$chrome
$chrome$chromedriverVersion
[1] "2.40.565386 (45a059dc425e08165f9a10324bd1380cc13ca363)"

$chrome$userDataDir
[1] "/var/folders/zx/2szdmkts3rdc6kw689l75gzw0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.O99TsL"


$cssSelectorsEnabled
[1] TRUE

$databaseEnabled
[1] FALSE

$handlesAlerts
[1] TRUE

$hasTouchScreen
[1] FALSE

$javascriptEnabled
[1] TRUE

$locationContextEnabled
[1] TRUE

$mobileEmulationEnabled
[1] FALSE

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$networkConnectionEnabled
[1] FALSE

$pageLoadStrategy
[1] "normal"

$platform
[1] "Mac OS X"

$rotatable
[1] FALSE

$setWindowRect
[1] TRUE

$takesHeapSnapshot
[1] TRUE

$takesScreenshot
[1] TRUE

$unexpectedAlertBehaviour
[1] ""

$version
[1] "67.0.3396.87"

$webStorageEnabled
[1] TRUE

$webdriver.remote.sessionid
[1] "78f931249b9975ea0fb10c03c581f6d1"

$id
[1] "78f931249b9975ea0fb10c03c581f6d1"
```

Comment: selenium version  , chrome browser and driver version.

Comment: RSelenium 1.7.3, sorry, but where can I find the rest?

Comment: Added some additional info

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded older version of Chrome instead of the newest and seems to be working